# HandlebarsJS : Change the text color depending what text value is?

Tags: html, html-table, handlebars.js, handlebars.java

Within my `handlebars` email `HTML` template I have the following table:

```
<div class="table">
        <table id="carTable">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Car Number</th>
                <th>owner</th>
            </tr>
            <!-- {{#each car}} -->
            <tr>
                <td>{{carNumber}}</td>
                <td>{{owner}}</td>
            </tr>
            <!--{{/each}} -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Is it possible that if the value of `{{owner}}` is e.g. "foo" then the text will be red, and if the value is "bar" then it will be blue etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With handlebars you'd need to write something like this:

```
<tr {{#if owner === "foo"}} class="red-text" {{/if}}>{{owner}}</tr>
```

[Check out this example](https://code-maven.com/handlebars-conditionals)